# Error - Google Maps Cordova Plugin installation

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am getting this error in the terminal --

> cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID=androidkey --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS=ioskey --save
>   ✖ Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
>           You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.
>           [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add
>           https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multi... (exit
>           code 1):
>           Error: Failed to fetch plugin
>           https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps
>           via registry.
>           Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is
>           incorrect.
>           Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
>           Failed to get absolute path to installed module

It's not my connection. I have tried this in another app and it seems to work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this in my ionic project with some bold steps as follows:

1. In your editor (I use VS Code), search for all instances of the text `cordova-plugin-googlemaps`: I found them in `config.xml,package.json & package-lock.json`
2. Delete all these instances from those files.
3. Also, delete the file `package-lock.json` for good measure
4. Remove all platforms (`android` or `ios`) from your project
5. Delete the following folders from your project: `platforms,plugins,www`
6. Add the `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` (At this point, it should successfully save it in `config.xml`)
7. Add your platforms
8. Then run your application

Answer (score 1):

Please try

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID=androidkey --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS=ioskey --save

Comment: This is it man!! you're awesome !!

Answer (score 0):

Could you show me the result of this command (**with --verbose option**)?

```
$>cordova plugin add http://https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID=... --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS=... --verbose
```

If you open the project with Android Studio 3.0 Preview, you may face this error by gradlew.

solution 1:

```
$> chmod +x platforms/android/gradlew
```

solution 2:

```
$> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googlemaps
$> cordova platform rm android
$> cordova plugin add http://https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID=... --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS=...
$> cordova platform add android
```

solution 3:
    Open the project with Android Studio, and fix the gradle version to 3.5 (or 3.3)